# Outlook 2010 font foreground/background color CSS not playing nice together

Tags: html, css, background-color, html-email, outlook-2010

So, I'm making a MIME message for Outlook 2010 formatted in `HTML` and `CSS`.

Here is the `HTML` that I'm generating:

```
<!DOCTYPE PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>asdfasdf</title>
</head>

<body>

<div style="text-align:left;">
<span style="font-family:'Tahoma';font-size:1em;">
<span style="background-color:#E6E501;">
<span style="color:#0013D6;">asfdasdfad</span></span></span></div>

<div style="text-align:left;">
<span style="font-family:'Tahoma';font-size:1em;">
<span style="background-color:#0A00CE;">
<span style="color:#01D6DE;">asdfasdfasdf</span></span></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the editor looks like before generating:

[image: Our program]

Here is what Outlook 2010 displays:

[image: Outlook 2010]

Here is the same `HTML` in an online editor:

[image]

What the heck is going on here?  Why is the font color only working for the light color background in Outlook and not the dark color background?  Has anyone else had this problem?
According to this website: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ CSS `color` and `background-color` tags should both be supported by Outlook 2010.

Also, I made individual spans so I can easily see what is going on.  This is not default behavior on our end, just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In email, you should be using tables instead of divs. You should also declare your background colors with html's bgcolor="" attribute like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#E6E501" style="font-family:'Tahoma', sans-serif; sans; font-size:14px; color:#0013D6;">
       asfdasdfad
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#0A00CE" style="font-family:'Tahoma', sans-serif; sans; font-size:14px; color:#01D6DE;">
       asdfasdfasdf
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I also added your font sizes in pixels and a fallback for your font. Normally you would set a width="" on your tables also, but I left it off as it better matches your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've looked at a couple of your other answers for these types of questions.  Why on earth does Outlook want formatted `table`s instead of `div`s.  What gives?  This seems very unnatural considering I'm not working with tables at all.

Comment: @ToastyMallows It is because Outlook uses the Microsoft Word engine to render html. This non-web browser renderer injects a bunch of additional code. Tables, which can use inline html tags like bgcolor simply produce better, more consistent results across Outlook and other email clients. If interested in learning more about email standards: [http://www.email-standards.org/](http://www.email-standards.org/)

Comment: In short: Outlook is hopeless at rendering html. Microsoft love standards - that's why they have 120 different ones.